# Pandas - Extract Specific Values between Parenthesis

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas series that contains various timezones and the unique values are as follows:

```
{0: '(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)',
 1: '(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London',
 2: '(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna',
 3: '(GMT) UTC - Coordinated Universal Time',
 4: '(GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey',
 5: '(GMT 00:00) Ponta Delgada (Azores)',
 6: '(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (Cancún, Quintana Roo, Mexico)',
 7: '(GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)',
 8: '(GMT-07:00) Arizona',
 9: '(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)',
 10: '(GMT+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague',
 11: '(GMT) Casablanca, Monrovia',
 12: '(GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic',
 13: '(GMT+08:00) Perth'}
```

I want to extract the `GMT` part from these strings. All the answers I found talks about extracting strings from parenthesis but not about specific values between the parenthesis.

**Expected Output:**

```
{0: 'GMT-05:00',
 1: 'GMT',
 2: 'GMT+01:00',
 3: 'GMT',
 4: 'GMT-06:00',
 5: 'GMT 00:00',
 6: 'GMT-05:00',
 7: 'GMT-05:00',
 8: 'GMT-07:00',
 9: 'GMT-06:00',
 10: 'GMT+01:00',
 11: 'GMT',
 12: 'GMT-02:00',
 13: 'GMT+08:00'}
```

I'd really appreciate your help since I'm not at all good with `regex`.

**EDITED**

I have tried `s.str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*', expand=True)` which gives me second last values between brackets so if a string contains `(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)` it will `(US & Canada)`. I have also tried searching for just `s.str.extract('[GMT]', expand=True)` but it gives me an error.

Comment: From your example, it seems you need to extract everything between the first set of parentheses, for which the capturing group can be `'\((.*?)\)'` If there are rows where this is not the case, maybe it's in the second or third set of parentheses, perhaps add those as test cases.

Comment: Try `\((GMT[^()]*)\)`

Comment: @revo - This regex works which is what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract everything between two parenthesis use `\((.*?)\)`

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = {} # data dictionary
pattern = "\((.*?)\)"

df = pd.Series(data)
new_data = {}

key = 0
for item in df.items():
    new_data[key] = re.match(pattern, item[1])[1]
    key += 1

print(new_data)

#new_df = pd.Series(new_data)
#print(new_df)
```

explanation: https://regex101.com/r/5XjNqh/1